# Can someone explain how to prove this equality with respect to Dirac-Delta function?

Tags: dirac-delta

I saw the following equations.

$$
\begin{align}
\delta(ax) &= \frac {1} {\lvert a \rvert} \delta(x)\\
\delta(x^2-a^2) &= \frac {1} {2\lvert a \rvert} \left [ {\delta(x+a) + \delta(x-a)} \right ] 
\end{align}$$

I think the equation below is the general expression.
    Can someone let me know how the equation below is induced?

$$
\delta \left [ g(x) \right ]=\sum_i \frac { \delta(x-x_i) } { g'(x_i) }
$$

Please don't use slang and abbreviations.
I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: you will find loads of proofs in the web:
http://academic.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Delta%20Functions/Simplified%20Dirac%20Delta.pdf

Comment: Thank you for a good document. :) I should print this out tomorrow, and read up.